# Acts 2:6: What does τῆς φωνῆς ταύτης refer to?

Tags: greek, acts

The Greek text of Acts 2:6 according to both the [Textus Receptus](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Act&c=2&t=KJV#s=t_conc_1020006) and [NA28](http://www.nestle-aland.com/en/read-na28-online/text/bibeltext/lesen/stelle/54/20001/29999/) states,

> γενομένης δὲ τῆς φωνῆς ταύτης συνῆλθεν τὸ πλῆθος καὶ συνεχύθη ὅτι ἤκουον εἷς ἕκαστος τῇ ἰδίᾳ διαλέκτῳ λαλούντων αὐτῶν

What does τῆς φωνῆς ταύτης refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the phrase "this sound" could refer to either the sound of the wind (vs. 2) or the speaking in tongues (vs. 4), several facts point to "this sound" being the speaking in tongues.

1. The most recent antecedent for the pronoun "this" would be the believers speaking in tongues in vs. 4.

> [2:4](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Acts+2:4) All of them were filled with the Holy Spirit, and they began to speak in other languages as the Spirit enabled them. [NET Bible]

2. The sound of the wind is described using a different word (ἦχος) in verse 2.

> [2:2](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Acts+2:2) Suddenly a sound (ἦχος) like a violent wind blowing came from heaven and filled the entire house where they were sitting. [NET]

3. The rest of 6, 7, and 8 refer to the speaking in tongues and not the wind. It would be an odd shift for Luke to mean that the sound of the wind drew them in and then they concentrated on the speaking without telling. His use of different words for the two sounds (ἦχος and φωνῆς) is an indication that it is not the sound of wind that drew the crowd.

> [2:6](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Acts+2:6) When **this sound** occurred, a crowd gathered and was in confusion, **because** each one **heard them speaking** in his own language. 2:7 Completely baffled, they said, “Aren’t all these who are **speaking** Galileans? 2:8 And how is it that each one of us hears in our own **native language**?..." [NET, emphasis added]